# Special SQL windows function that works like a loop

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, window-functions, recursive-query

I’m looking for some kind of SQL window function that calculate values based on a calculated value from a previous iteration when looping over the window. I’m not looking for ‘lag’ which will just take the original value of the previous row.

Here is the case: We have web analytics sessions. We would like to attribute to each session to the last relevant channel. There are 3 channels: **direct**, **organic** and **paid**. However, they have different priorities: **paid** will always be relevant. **Organic** will only be relevant if there was no **paid** channel in the last 30 days and **direct** would only be relevant if there was not **paid** or **organic** channel in the last 30 days
So in the example table we would like to calculate the values in column ‘attributed’ based on channel and the date columns. Note, the data is there for several users so this should be calculated per user.

```
+─────────────+───────+──────────+─────────────+
| date        | user  | channel  | attributed  |
+─────────────+───────+──────────+─────────────+
| 2022-01-01  | 123   | direct   | direct      |
| 2022-01-14  | 123   | paid     | paid        |
| 2022-02-01  | 123   | direct   | paid        |
| 2022-02-12  | 123   | direct   | paid        |
| 2022-02-13  | 123   | organic  | paid        |
| 2022-03-08  | 123   | direct   | direct      |
| 2022-03-10  | 123   | paid     | paid        |
+─────────────+───────+──────────+─────────────+
```

So in the table above row 1 is attributed **direct** because it’s the first line. The second then is **paid** as this has priority to direct. It stays **paid** for the next 2 sessions as **direct** has lower priority, then it switches to **organic** as the **paid** attribution is older than 30 days. The last one is then **paid** again as it has a higher priority than **organic**.

I would know how to solve it if you could decide whether a new channel needs to be attributed only based on the current row and the previous. I added here the SQL to do it:

```
with source as ( -- example data
select cast("2022-01-01" as date) as date, 123 as user, "direct" as channel
union all
select "2022-01-14", 123, "paid"
union all
select "2022-02-01", 123, "direct"
union all
select "2022-02-12", 123, "direct"
union all
select "2022-02-13", 123, "organic"
union all
select "2022-03-08", 123, "direct"
union all
select "2022-03-10", 123, "paid"
),
flag_new_channel as( -- flag sessions that would override channel informaton ; this only works statically here
  select *,
    case 
      when lag(channel) over (partition by user order by date) is null then 1
      when date_diff(date,lag(date) over (partition by user order by date),day)>30 then 1
      when channel = "paid" then 1
      when channel = "organic" and lag(channel) over (partition by user order by date)!='paid' then 1 
      else 0
      end flag

   from source
   qualify flag=1
)

select s.*,
f.channel attributed_channel, 
row_number() over (partition by s.user, s.date order by f.date desc) rn -- number of flagged previous sessions
from source s
left join flag_new_channel f
on s.date>=f.date
qualify rn=1 --only keep the last flagged session at or before the current session
```

However, this would for example set "organic" in row 5 because it doesn't know "paid" is still relevant.

```
+─────────────+───────+──────────+─────────────────────+
| date        | user  | channel  | attributed_channel  |
+─────────────+───────+──────────+─────────────────────+
| 2022-01-01  | 123   | direct   | direct              |
| 2022-01-14  | 123   | paid     | paid                |
| 2022-02-01  | 123   | direct   | paid                |
| 2022-02-12  | 123   | direct   | paid                |
| 2022-02-13  | 123   | organic  | organic             |
| 2022-03-08  | 123   | direct   | organic             |
| 2022-03-10  | 123   | paid     | paid                |
+─────────────+───────+──────────+─────────────────────+
```

Any ideas? Not sure recursive queries can help or udfs. I’m using BigQuery usually but if you know solutions in other dialects it would still be interesting to know.

Comment: Never mind folks, i also didn't find anything on the internet on this topic. It seems to be the weekest point of sql window functions that they don't have access to loop state/variables. There seesm to be a way to use udf on arrays that come out of an array_agg over a window that goes from unlimited preceeding to current row. Still this would mean to recalculate the session history redundantly for each row.

Comment: No need for UDF.  This can be done.  It's just that your story was a little unfocused, with use of poorly defined terms.  It could have been more concise/clear, and with a complete test case (actual SQL) and with your attempted SQL.

Comment: good point @JonArmstrong. I don't have even an idea how to solve it. But i have a version that would work if the decision for overriding the channel could be done for each session individually. I'll add it into the question

Comment: Note: Your story has errors, ambiguity.  I think the answer provided below is what you intended to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

**Updated: Corrected.  I lost track of your correct / expected result, due to the confusing story.**

For PostgreSQL, we can do something like this (with CTE and window functions):

[The fiddle for PG 14](https://dbfiddle.uk/6nGdWTWJ)

- pri - provides a table of (channel, priority) pairs
- cte0 - provides the test data
- cte1 - determines the minimum priority over the last 30 days per user
- final - the final query expression obtains the attributed channel name

```
WITH pri (channel, pri) AS (
       VALUES ('paid'    , 1)
            , ('organic' , 2)
            , ('direct'  , 3)
     )
   , cte0 (date, xuser, channel) AS (
       VALUES
          ('2022-01-01'::date, 123, 'direct')
        , ('2022-01-14'      , 123, 'paid')
        , ('2022-02-01'      , 123, 'direct')
        , ('2022-02-12'      , 123, 'direct')
        , ('2022-02-13'      , 123, 'organic')
        , ('2022-03-08'      , 123, 'direct')
        , ('2022-03-10'      , 123, 'paid')
     )
   , cte1 AS (
       SELECT cte0.*
            , pri.pri
            , MIN(pri) OVER (PARTITION BY xuser ORDER BY date
                             RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                            ) AS mpri
         FROM cte0
         JOIN pri
           ON pri.channel = cte0.channel
     )
  SELECT cte1.*
       , pri.channel AS attributed
  FROM cte1
  JOIN pri
    ON pri.pri = cte1.mpri
;
```

The result:

| date | xuser | channel | pri | mpri | attributed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 123 | direct | 3 | 3 | direct |
| 2022-01-14 | 123 | paid | 1 | 1 | paid |
| 2022-02-01 | 123 | direct | 3 | 1 | paid |
| 2022-02-12 | 123 | direct | 3 | 1 | paid |
| 2022-02-13 | 123 | organic | 2 | 1 | paid |
| 2022-03-08 | 123 | direct | 3 | 2 | organic |
| 2022-03-10 | 123 | paid | 1 | 1 | paid |

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon. Didn't think about the range clause with the date (indeed BigQuery wouldn't support this, but that's solvable) .